# How to verify if my list with checkbox are all checked using Angular 5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I created a list with one checkbox for each item, and I need to verify if all of them are ckecked.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="ingredient-list" >
   <li class="btn-list" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients">
        <label class="checky round">
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <span></span>
          <span>{{ ingredient }}</span>
        </label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried already to solve this problem?

Comment: I quite close now, I'm getting the ul element, but when I check if any input is checked the return is underfined, should be true or false

Answer (score 0):

in your component ts file

```
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

ingredientsForm;
constructor( private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
   //do what you need to get your recipe details first
   const ingredientFGs = recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => this.fb.group(ingredient));

ingredientFGs.forEach(item => {
   item.addControl('isChecked', new FormControl());
   item.get('isChecked').setValue(false);
   item.get('isChecked').setValidators(Validators.requiredTrue);
})

this.ingredientsForm = this.fb.group({
   ingredients: this.fb.array(ingredientFGs);
});
}
```

and in your html

```
<form [formGroup]="ingredientsForm">
   <ul class="ingredient-list" formArrayName="ingredients">
      <li class="btn-list" *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients.controls">
          <label class="checky round">
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isChecked">
              <span></span>
              <span>{{ ingredient.value() }}</span>
          </label>
      </li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

then doing ingredientsForm.valid will return true if everything is checked

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that was really helpful but I didn't want to include all these modules for this only propose, so I came up with another solution which I will answer now

Answer (score 0):

As I dind'nt wanted to import others modules just for solve this problem I came up with another idea.

I created a method at my component.ts to verify the checkbox:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipes.component.css']
})
export class RecipesComponent  {

  @ViewChild('ingredientList') ingredientList: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('preparationList') preparationList: ElementRef;



  isAllChecked(list: ElementRef): boolean{
    // take the inputs by tag and convert to array
    var inputs = [].slice.call(list.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input'));

    return !inputs.some(function(input){
        // verify if any item is not checked
        return input.ckecked == false;        
    });
  } 
}
```

My HTML looks like this now

```
<ul #ingredientList >
  <li  #item class="btn-list" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients">
    <label class="checky round">
      <input type="checkbox" >
      <span></span>
      <span>{{ ingredient }}</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks everyone for the help